# Multiple Google Charts from one Google Spreadsheet Only Displaying 1 Chart

Tags: google-apps-script, google-visualization

When I previously used google charts, I was able to use a script tag to insert one chart at a time, so I would use a script tag separately for each google chart. An example of this below:

https://jsfiddle.net/Muvew/zystef14/

Recently I have been working on replacing these charts with ones that use a google Spreadsheets data table. However, when using the same idea for these charts, an issue occurs, they seem to appear, almost as if one chart is replacing another.

I have a feeling its something to do with the setOnLoadCallBack function but Im not sure as it worked in the previous setup. Ive attached a JSFiddle of the second set of charts below:

https://jsfiddle.net/Muvew/00gepgq0/

For reference, below is a template of new chart template I am using:

```
<script>
    google.load("visualization", '1', {packages:['corechart', 'bar']});
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        function drawChart() {
          var query = new google.visualization.Query(
              'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Fp3iz5zmzF4KgnlF4Me4OA3c8Msu0FV4_x1eS16WN-0/edit?usp=sharing');
            query.setQuery('SELECT A, B, C, D');
          query.send(handleQueryResponse);
        }

        function handleQueryResponse(response) {
          if (response.isError()) {
            alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
            return;
          }

          var data = response.getDataTable();
            for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
                console.log(data.getColumnType(i));
            }
          var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('columnchart'));
          chart.draw(data);
        }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using same function names for the second chart. Refer the below code.

```html
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script>
 google.load("visualization", '1', {packages:['corechart', 'bar']});
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart_1);
  function drawChart() {
    var query = new google.visualization.Query(
     'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Fp3iz5zmzF4KgnlF4Me4OA3c8Msu0FV4_x1eS16WN-0/edit?usp=sharing');
            query.setQuery('SELECT A, B, C, D');
    query.send(handleQueryResponse);
  }

  function handleQueryResponse(response) {
    if (response.isError()) {
   alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
   return;
    }

    var data = response.getDataTable();
            for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
            }
    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('columnchart'));
    chart.draw(data);
  }
    
  function drawChart_1() {
    var query = new google.visualization.Query(
     'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Fp3iz5zmzF4KgnlF4Me4OA3c8Msu0FV4_x1eS16WN-0/edit?usp=sharing');
            query.setQuery('SELECT A, E, F');
    query.send(handleQueryResponse_1);
  }

  function handleQueryResponse_1(response) {
    if (response.isError()) {
   alert('Error in query: ' + response.getMessage() + ' ' + response.getDetailedMessage());
   return;
    }

    var data = response.getDataTable();
            for (var i = 0; i < data.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
            }
    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('testchart'));
    chart.draw(data);
  }
  </script>
</head>
 <body>
 <div id='columnchart'></div>
  </body>
  <body>
  <div id='testchart'></div>
  </body>
```